# .htaccess to mask url and redirect domain name to subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mask

Hi folks
I'd appreciate some .htaccess advice.

I have two wordpress installations. "A" which is in my ISP's Linux server root directory and "B", which is in a subdirectory of the same server called "directoryB".

Actual structure is:=
A.com
A.com/directoryB/

I own two domain names A.com and B.com. I want people to use the address B.com when accessing everything on directoryB, not A.com/directoryB/.

I want to leave the "real" "A" alone - no redirections!

I have been assured this can be done using the .htaccess file, but I've failed so far!
I have managed to "mask" the home page of "B" using cPanel, but it reverts back to A.com/directoryB/ once you move away from the home page. I'm also not sure if the .htaccess ought to be in the root or subdirectory.

All I want is to mask the A.com/directoryB/ with B.com/ every time it appears on the address bar......

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a .htaccess file in directoryB and see if it works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^B.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://B.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Compeek. I tried this last night and it gives me a 500 internal server error once I try to move away from the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in .htaccess in your root directory -

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

Redirect permanent /directoryB http://B.com

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi & thanks Lobo! This feels in the "nearly there" category! This works for the home page, but when I try to go elsewhere on the site, the page doesn't change and address bar just shows "B.com/index.html" and doesn't show the real address  eg "www.b.com/about/"

Comment: Strange, I don't see a reason for it. Does `www.A.com/directoryB/about` work? URL doesn't change? Could you also post the content of .htaccess in your `directoryB` in your question?

Comment: Hi again Lobo,I've posted my htaccess from directoryB and also spent a few more frustrating hours trying to tweak it - to no avail!

Comment: I'm not sure. It should work from what I can see. backup directoryB's htaccess, remove it, add some directories, htmls and try accessing them using b.com as well as a.com/directoryB. You might get some idea. also, can you replace `RewriteRule . /directoryB/index.php [L]` with `RewriteRule . http://B.com/index.php [L]` in your directoryB htaccess and try?

Answer (score 0):

The htaccess in public_html is:-

```
# BEGIN WordPress  
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On  
Redirect permanent /directoryB http://B.com  
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]*)/$ /test/login/?id=$1  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  
</IfModule>  
  
# END WordPress  
Options -Indexes  
  
=============== this is the htaccess from "directoryB"  
  
# BEGIN WordPress  
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /directoryB/  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /directoryB/index.php [L]  
</IfModule>  
  
# END WordPress  
Options -Indexes
```