# Redirect a wordpress sub-page to a different domain using mod_rewrite

Tags: wordpress, url, mod-rewrite, ssl, url-masking

I am trying to mask https://mydomain.com/free to www.myotherdomain.com so that when www.myotherdomain.com or myotherdomain.com is entered it loads the page at mydomain.com but shows myotherdomain.com in the address bar as well as keeps a ssl connection through mydomain.com without having to use an iframe, is this possible, I am fairly  new to working with .htaccess and mod_rewrite my .htaccess code is as follows

```
# BEGIN WordPress

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^javitaonlinecafe\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://freejavitacoffee.com [R=301,L]

# END WordPress
```

Comment: is entered it loads the page at mydomain.com/free * forgot to specify the subpage

Comment: myotherdomain is a add on domain to my 1and1  hosting business server

Comment: Did you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042828/htaccess-to-mask-url-and-redirect-domain-name-to-subdirectory?

Comment: Here's another nice article http://www.htmlremix.com/css/permanent-url-masking-for-mirroring-website-using-php-and-htaccess